# Retrofit with GsonConverterFactory

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I got this gson format:

```
{
"ltc_btc":{
    "high":105.41,
    "low":104.67,
    "avg":105.04,
    "vol":43398.22251455,
    "vol_cur":4546.26962359,
    "last":105.11,
    "buy":104.2,
    "sell":105.11,
    "updated":1418654531
}
...
```

I'm  trying to parse it by GsonCoverterFactory, but it works only if a declare it like this:

```
@SerializedName("ltc_btc")
@Expose
TickerPoint pair;
```

But its not solve the problem cause "ltc_bts" always is different. Any ideas?

P.S I tried HashMap - the same NPE.

Comment: ltc_bts key will dynamic means use dynamic way to gson convert

Comment: what should I do?  any code or links maybe?)

Comment: "ltc_btc" keywoard is changing ? or whole object body ?

Comment: only key is changing

Comment: @IvanSablin You query the same endpoint and it returns differently structured jsons every time? I find this hard to believe. Could you provide the whole json returned by the API?

Comment: Key is the same with path. For ex: https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/ltc_btc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the solution:

```
public Observable<TickerResponse> getTicker(YobitPublic api, String first_coin, String second_coin) {
    Call<JsonObject> call = api.getTickerObservable(first_coin + "_" + second_coin);
    return Observable.create( emitter -> {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                JsonObject jsonObject = response.body();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                TickerResponse tickerResponse;
                Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> set = jsonObject.entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> obj : set) {
                    String key = obj.getKey();
                    if (jsonObject.get(key) != null) {
                        TickerPoint point = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get(key).toString(), TickerPoint.class);
                        if (point != null && point.getServer_time() != 0) {
                            tickerResponse = new TickerResponse(key, point);
                            emitter.onNext(tickerResponse);
                            emitter.onComplete();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                emitter.onError(new Throwable("Error"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                emitter.onError(t);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly 'ltc_bts' key is your Object class name. You need to deserialize your json to your object.

Just pass your Class in your parameter , then when you need it just serialize with parameter's class.

Comment: Look for some links,  but still do  not understand what  i should do :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for "ltc_btc" (or whatever it is,maybe "eth_btc. If the value Object is the same you need one template).

```
public class CryptoCurrencyExchangeModel {
//one of this fields for you must be primary. that field must never be null

    @SerializedName("high")
    private Double high;

    @SerializedName("low")
    private Double low;

    @SerializedName("avg")
    private Double avg;

    @SerializedName("vol")
    private Double vol;

    @SerializedName("vol_cur")
    private Double vol_cur;

    @SerializedName("last")
    private Double last;

    @SerializedName("buy")
    private Double buy;

    @SerializedName("sell")
    private Double sell;

    @SerializedName("updated")
    private Long updated;


}
```

Now  you need to parse your json to JsonObject. In this case json is a String which you will get from Retrofit response.

```
JSONObject currencyJsonObject = new JSONObject("{
"ltc_btc":{
    "high":105.41,
    "low":104.67,
    "avg":105.04,
    "vol":43398.22251455,
    "vol_cur":4546.26962359,
    "last":105.11,
    "buy":104.2,
    "sell":105.11,
    "updated":1418654531
}");
```

After that you need to get keys from JsonObject and iterate over it and get your desired object.

```
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
    CryptoCurrencyExchangeModel cryptoCurrencyExchangeModel;
    Gson gson;
    while( keys.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
           cryptoCurrencyExchangeModel = gson.fromJson(jObject.get(key).toString(), CryptoCurrencyExchangeModel);
           if(cryptoCurrencyExchangeModel != null && cryptoCurrencyExchangeModel.buy != null){
      //here you do what you want
}
        }
    }
```